# How is object created as line using createline stored in .tab file?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I used Mapbasic and made data imported from excel into mappable and added projection to WGS 84  and updated table using:

```
update TABLE set obj = createline(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

to create line and the line was create which I could see in mapper window but when I looked at the browser window the no of column has not changed. How is this obj created stored in table in .tab file as I can see spatial coordinate in MS SQL table.

Comment: Is this a native table or a MS SQL linked table?

Comment: @Nathan W This is native table

Comment: If you open up your tab file, you'll see there's simply a link for the database.  When you upload the data, or create the data, you have an option, iirc, of live access, or linked.  If it is live, it downloads all the data, if linked, all the data stays server side.  As I said, iirc.

Comment: @Hairy I could not understand :(

Comment: Open the tab file in notepad++ (there are other editors) and have a look at the code in there; it will tell you how you open the database and have the data.  A live link means you don't have data on the client, but work on it at the DB level, if it you create a copy of it, you create a local copy of the data.  Again, iirc.  If you are using live link, you may need to refresh the view, to force the changes into MapInfo; it is an area to look into, and something I thought *could* be an issue, but it's not an answer, hence the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapInfo will not let you see the spatial data in the browser, it is only visible in the map. 
MapInfo stores the spatial data (your lines) in the map file and the alphanumerical data in the .DAT (.TXT, .XLS or whatever format you are using).

If you need to see some parts of the spatial data inside MI Pro, you need to query these parts using SQL Select.

Comment: If there's a direct link, there is no DAT file Peter.

Comment: If there is no .DAT, then you have your data in another format, which cann be .XLS, .TXT, .DBF or a number of other formats. The .ID file "links" the alphanumerical data (in the .DAT, .XLS or whatever) with the spatial data in the .MAP file.

Comment: Peter, no, sorry, but you've not understood the problem/question.  If the data is live linked to the spatial data in the database, there is **no** DAT/XLS/DBF/TXT or anything, it is **live linked** to the data in the DB.  The only time a DAT file (or others) is created, is if you store, or wish to access, the data locally.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that one. If it is live without cache, the data (alphanumericla as well as spatial is stored in memory). If it is live with cache, it is stored in a set of files kept in the temp folder.

Comment: No worries, that was what I was trying to convey.

Answer (score -3):

Update table set obj=createline(Long_B,Lat_B,Long_A,Lat_a)

Comment: Please provide additional information. As it stands, it does not answer the question of how the object is created & stored.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  A good answer should include explanation on how to solve the problem, not just a single line of code.  Please [edit] your answer to include additional info on how and why your answer is the answer.