# Creating migration flow map using MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, migration, flow-map

my first post on this forum :)
Being a beginner in Mapinfo, I didn't find any tutorial on creating a thematic map of migration flows, something like;

[image]

or

[image]

I tried [Arrow40](http://www.mapinfotools.com/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=10&sobi2Id=335&Itemid=53) extension but couldn't get nice results.

Any ideas/hints for Mapinfo? any alternative software that is specialized on that? or should I just create the map in Photoshop?

Answer (score 1):

The Spider graph tool might be able to help you here, but it would require a degree of manipulation to get right - which if you're proficient in photoshop you might be better off doing it in there, pending the complexity of the data.

As a really rough guide, and shamelessly lifted from Pete over at MI-L:

1. Keep your base data file, but create a 2nd file for your destination.
2. Create a field in both files that is identical - you need this for the spidergraph tool to run the link between "from" (your base file) and "to".
3. After running the spider graph tool and creating the "spider file" you can produce a ranged thematic map using your migration numbers and select a line style that has arrows.

As a general comment, MapInfo is great at many things, cartographic output isn't one of them.

Comment: Agree on most points here - what's missed is the mighty MapBasic command: update point_table setobj=createline(Start_X, Start_Y,End_X,End_Y)

Comment: For more detail see here: http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/techsupp/miprod.nsf/kbase_by_product/704C383D587B1F848525654D006DA6E3

Comment: Thanks @AndrewTice .. That article was there a decade and a half! Last Modified: 11/14/2000 :)

Comment: ...still the fastest way I know of to join points though - I have form in this area...http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56932/how-to-write-an-equivalent-to-mapbasics-createline-in-pyqgis